# Prevent MPMoviePlayerController controls from showing when video starts

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a long queue of controllers, each with their own short videos. They're organized in a `UIPageViewController`, and when each video finishes, it displays the next VC without animation. The idea is to look like it's one big movie with jump cuts. I have the functionality mostly there, but every time a new clip loads, it presents the controls at the bottom. Is there anyway of prevent this apart from making my own controls?

Comment: Please add some code how you are doing this, or else it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to hide the control bar:

```
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```